# laravel get reading comprehension multiple choice questions and single mcq's in single exam

Tags: php, laravel

I have two types of requirements.

1) Quiz with straight forward questions and multiple choice answer (single answer)

2) Quiz with reading comprehension with its set of questions and some assorted questions then passage again. (There is no particular order in which passages and random questions appear)

I have implemented task 1 by building the following tables.

```
Table( questions)
        $table->integer('quiz_id')->index();
        $table->integer('question_no')->index();
        $table->text('question');
        $table->text('quiz_ans_1');
        $table->text('quiz_ans_2');
        $table->text('quiz_ans_3');
        $table->text('quiz_ans_4');

Table (answers)
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('question_id');
        $table->integer('quiz_id')->index();
        $table->integer('question_no')->index();
        $table->string('answer');
```

For normal straight forward quiz it works great as in blade template I can pull a question title and answers and run a "foreach" loop.

For task 2 ,I am confused where to put the reading comprehension passages in database and pull them in blade as described in test format which vary from exam to exam.

Few problems :-

1) If model "passages" with hasMany('App\Questions') is created. Then when I call a quiz and pull blade then it will show only passages and questions related to it and ignore . But there will be many single questions which needs to be pulled.

2) If model "questions" belongsTo Passage is created it is defining that every question belongs to some passage which is not the case.

I want to implement the following in a instance of online test :-

1) section 1 ->  "n" number of questions which are independent

2) section 2 -> three reading comprehension passages with their own set of  questions (numbers vary)

3) section 3 -> "m" questions which are independent

4) section 4 -> two reading comprehension passages with their own set of  questions (numbers vary)

total questions (n+m+l)= 100 (or 200 which is fixed)

It would be great help if some can put me in right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your questions polymorphic. Meaning they could belong to the test (independent questions), to a passage (passage questions) or to a quiz (quiz questions). Read about polymorphic relationships here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

**Questions table**

```
id - integer
questionable_id - integer
questionable_type - string
```

Because your questions are polyphormic now, you cannot have `quiz_ans_1`, `quiz_ans_2`, etc. anymore. So you make a table for them

**Options table**

```
id - integer
question_id - integer
content - text
```

Then you have your models Test (or Exam), Passage, Quizz, Question, Option, Answer. In these models, add a relationship to Question model

```
public function questions() {
    return $this->morphMany(Question::class, 'questionable');
}
```

in Question model add

```
public function questionable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Btw, in table answers, remove `quiz_id`. `question_id` is enough to know what it belongs to. Besides, you can answer to any question, not only quiz questions.

Now in your exam/test you can get them like this

```
//get the exam first
$exam = Exam::with('questions')->find($examid);

//$exam hasMany [quizz, passages, questions] (independant questions)

//quiz questions
$quiz = Quiz::with('questions')->where('exam_id', $exam->id)->first();

//passage questions
$passages = Passage::with('questions')->where('exam_id', $exam->id)->get();

//independant questions
$questions = $exam->questions;
```

In your view, you can display like this

```
//1. Section 1, 10 independent questions
@php $firstTenQuestions = $questions->take(10); @endphp
@foreach($firstTenQuestions->all() as $question)
    {{ $question->content }}
@endforeach

//2. Reading passages (3)
@php $firstThreeReadings = $readings->take(3); @endphp
@foreach($firstThreeReadings->all() as $reading)
    {{ $reading->content }}

    @foreach($reading->questions as $question)
        {{ $question->content }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach

//3. Second set of independent questions 
// get questions from index 10 [11 - n]
@php $secondSet = $questions->splice(10); @endphp 
@foreach($secondSet->all() as $question)
    {{ $question->content }}
@endforeach

//4. Reading Passages (2)
// take from index 3, limit it to 2
@php $readings2 = $readings->splice(3, 2); @endphp
@foreach($readings2->all() as $reading)
    {{ $reading->content }}

    @foreach($reading->questions as $question)
        {{ $question->content }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This is not THE solution. But I'm sure you can build from this to get where you want. Learn about collection manipulations here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections

Comment: Thank you for the answer.It is a great way but only solves half the problem. 
The problem is we do not know if section one contains 10 questions . some times they can have 5 or 4 or 15. Same way with passages and its questions and rest of questions.They vary from test to test. How to mark them independent and passage related and bring them for every test. I want to standardise the template rather than having 100's of blade template. The only thing which is fixed are total number of questions.

Comment: In the Exam/Test table, add the number of question in a column like `section1_questions integer NOT NULL`. Then in the first loop you do `$firstTenQuestions = $questions->take($exam->section1_questions);`. You could apply the same thing to passages. That way, a single template is needed.

Comment: I have made few modifications and built on it like you suggested.It works like charm! Thanks a lot. Accepted as the answer.